# Angular Breadcrumb didn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breadcrumbs

first of all sorry for my bad English.

So, I want to add breadcrumb to my angular App. I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-breadcrumbs).  Everything seems to work but it's not. Here's what I got now - see links on bottom

grey row should be my breadcrumb. I don't have any errors in console.

This is how look like html - see links on the bottom

I don't know where is error or my mistake.

Here's some code.

app.js

```
'use strict';
/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name timeSheet2App
 * @description
 * # timeSheet2App
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
.module('timeSheet2App', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMdIcons',
    'appMenu',
    'appProfiles',
    'ngMdIcons',
    'loginApp',
    'calendarApp',
    'registryApp',
    'appConfiguration',
    'ui.calendar',
    'tasksApp',
    'ui.router',
    'ng-breadcrumbs',
    'breadCrumbs'
])

.config(config)
.run(run);

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];

function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', { templateUrl: '../views/profil.html', label: 'Profil' }
        )
    .when('/calendar', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/calendar/views/calendar.html',
        controller: 'CalendarCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        label: 'Calendar'
    })

    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/loginForm/views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        label: 'Login'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/registerForm/views/register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        label: 'Register'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about',
        label: 'About'
    })
    .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/menu/views/menu.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
    })
    .when('/menu', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/menu/views/menu.html'
    })
    .when('/profil', {
        templateUrl: 'views/profil.html'
    })
    .when('/404', {
        templateUrl: '404.html',
    })
    .when('/quicktasks', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/quicktasks/views/quicktasks.html',
        controller: 'QuickTasksCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .when('/breadcrumbs', {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/breadcrumbs/views/breadcrumbs.html',
        controller: 'BreadCrumbsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        label: 'Bread'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/404'
    });
}

run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];

function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
// keep user logged in after page refresh
$rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' +        $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
}

$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
    var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
    var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
    if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }
});
};
```

breadcrumbs.js

```
'use strict';

 /**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name timeSheet2App.controller:BreadcrumbsCtrl
 * @description
 * # BreadcrumbsCtrl
 * Controller of the timeSheet2App
 */
angular.module('breadCrumbs',[])
.controller('BreadCrumbsCtrl', BreadCrumbsCtrl);
BreadCrumbsCtrl.$inject =['breadcrumbs'];

function BreadCrumbsCtrl (breadcrumbs) {
var vm = this;
vm.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;
 };
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/modules/menu/styles/appMenu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/modules/profiles/styles/appProfiles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/modules/loginForm/styles/loginForm.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/modules/calendar/styles/calendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/modules/configuration/styles/appConfiguration.css">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body ng-app="timeSheet2App">
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<ol class="ab-nav breadcrumb">
<li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.get() track by breadcrumb.path" ng-class="{ active: $last }">
  <a ng-if="!$last" ng-href="#{{ breadcrumb.path }}" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label" class="margin-right-xs"></a>
  <span ng-if="$last" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label"></span>
</li>
</ol>
<div ng-view class="containers"></div>
<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
<script>
! function(A, n, g, u, l, a, r) {
A.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l, A[l] = A[l] || function() {
            (A[l].q = A[l].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, A[l].l = +new Date, a = n.createElement(g),
        r = n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0], a.src = u,         r.parentNode.insertBefore(a, r)
}(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-    analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/screenfull/dist/screenfull.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ng-breadcrumbs/dist/ng-breadcrumbs.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-material-icons/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src='bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/lang/pl.js'></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/loginForm/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/registerForm/controllers/RegisterCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/loginForm/services/authentication.service.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/loginForm/services/flash.service.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/loginForm/services/user.service.local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/menu/controller/menu.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/menu/service/getMenuData.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/menu/directive/menuLink.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/menu/directive/menuToggle.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/menu/directive/menuSidenav.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/profiles/controller/appProfiles.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/profiles/service/getDataProfiles.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/profiles/directive/profilMini.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/profiles/directive/settingProfil.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/profiles/directive/editProfilOption.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/calendar/controllers/CalendarCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/calendar/controllers/CalendarCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/configuration/controller/appConfiguration.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/configuration/directive/configurationModule.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/configuration/directive/configurationSetting.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/quicktasks/controllers/quicktasks.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/breadcrumbs/controllers/breadcrumbs.js">  </script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

and folders structure

- App

  - images
  - scripts

    - app.js
    - controllers
    - modules

      - breadcrumbs
      - calendar etc.
  - styles
  - views

Comment: This question has been very poorly formatted.  It's not obvious from reading the question what your actual issue is without any code presented, and your "links" forward to another page which has more links to other places.  At best, readers won't take the time to try to follow the trail to see the problem, and the question will be ignored.  At worst, it will be closed as off topic for not providing the code in the question itself.

Comment: I know that, I can't add more links because I'm new member. What Can I do?

Comment: Don't add links at all.  post all the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `breadcrumb` section in the index.html doesn't have any controller assigned to it, so it can't ever locate an instance of the `breadcrumb` object.  Also, you'll have to modify the HTML slightly to support the `controllerAs` syntax here.

Try this:

```
<div ng-controller="BreadCrumbsCtrl as breadctrl">
  <ol class="ab-nav breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadctrl.breadcrumbs.get() track by breadcrumb.path" ng-class="{ active: $last }">
      <a ng-if="!$last" ng-href="#{{ breadcrumb.path }}" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label" class="margin-right-xs"></a>
      <span ng-if="$last" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label"></span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Also, it looks like you declared `'breadCrumbs'` as it's own module, so you'll want to move the `ng-breadcrumbs` module injection from the `'timeSheet2App'` to `'breadcrumbs'`, e.g.:

```
angular.module('breadCrumbs',['ng-breadcrumbs'])
...

angular
.module('timeSheet2App', [
...
'ui.router',
//'ng-breadcrumbs', <-- no need for this here...
'breadCrumbs'
...
```

As a side note, I don't recommend using `controllerAs: 'vm'` for every controller in your app, it tends to make it harder to identify which controller is which, especially if you have nested controllers.  It's much better to name the `controllerAs` something similar to your actual controller name.

Comment: Work great! Thank you so much.